# able to delete only first element of dynamically created div element even after using .on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

using jquery 1.10.2
I want to delete the div element that contains the cross image.the code given below is only working for the first dynamically created div

```
$('#cross').on("click",function(e){

  jsPlumb.detachAllConnections($(this).parent());-->detaching jsplumb connections

  $(this).parent().remove();-->cross image is contained in the div element i want to           delete


   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Firstly, IDs must be unique. Secondly, you should delegate event

Comment: the ids are unique and the elements are  getting added to DOM properly

Comment: So you have only one element with ID `#cross`? Then i didn't understand your question... You should provide all relevant code in question and maybe you should be able to replicate your issue on jsFiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach listeners to document instead.
Replace `#cross` with what u need.

```
$(document).on("click","#cross",function(e){

  jsPlumb.detachAllConnections($(this).parent());-->detaching jsplumb connections

  $(this).parent().remove();-->cross image is contained in the div element i want to           delete


   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: thanks for edit, using my phone cant figure out how to format it as code through here... -.-

Comment: i meant click the green V under the number near my answer ;)